# Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException. Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have enabled permission for application to read images from the internet but i am still getting this in my log cat `BitmapFactory] Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /http:/c.files.bbci.co.uk/12F71/production/_96418677_ccc61cd3-1779-4850-b8e7-8c799e61094f.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[System.out] resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: http://c.files.bbci.co.uk/12F71/production/_96418677_ccc61cd3-1779-4850-b8e7-8c799e61094f.jpg`

I have read online to resolve this issue but it seems every one has a different answer as to why this happens.

I keep wondering why my image is not displaying. This is how i bind to the thumbnail in my adapter&holder class. Is there anything i need to check?

**AdapterHolder**

```
    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
                {
                    FeedViewHolder hold = holder as FeedViewHolder;

hold.txtImage.SetImageURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(myFeed.items[position].thumbnail));

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImageView.SetImageURI` only loads from a local/file-based Uri

> Note that you use this method to load images from a local Uri only.

re: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI(android.net.Uri)

You need to download/cache the remote file and then provide that local uri as your ImageView source.